How do I change the pitch of an AVSpeechUtterance object in the middle of the string or attributed string being spoken?
I'm not able to get the prosody contour attribute of AVSpeechUtterance(ssmlRepresentation:). Until I figure that out, I would like to use AVSpeechRepresentation(attributedString:). Is there a way to change the pitch using attributed string with AVSpeechUtterance? I'm trying to make the statement "Hi Daddy" like a little girl is saying it. Is that able to be done by IPA or attributed string?
Here is my code if it helps. I got it from another question on stackoverflow.
let voiceIdentifier = "com.apple.eloquence.en-US.Sandy"
let dst = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hi Daddy")
let pronunciationKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute)
let range = NSString(string: "Hi Daddy").range(of: "Hi Daddy")
dst.setAttributes([pronunciationKey: "ˈha͡ɪ.ˈdæ.di"], range: range)
let result = dst.copy() as! NSAttributedString
self.utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: result)
self.utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: voiceIdentifier)
self.utterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.0
self.utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
self.synthesizer.speak(self.utterance)

